# Use sigwait to block a specific signal without blocking SIGINT

Tags: c, macos, signals, posix, sigint

I have a program that runs a loop, each time at the end of the loop, the process should sleep for some seconds(the number of seconds is not constant and is calculated at each loop) or until the process receives `SIGINT`, I used `alarm()` and `sigwait()` to do this but it's blocking the `ctrl+c` signal(i.e `SIGINT`) which I don't want, I want `SIGINT` to be received and acted upon normally, sample code below (note that `somefunction()` below is just an example, in the original code it does real calculation instead of using `rand()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sigset_t sigs;

void setup_alarm()
{
    printf("setting up signals\n");
    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGALRM);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, NULL);
    
}
void wait_for_alarm(int interval)
{
    printf("setting up alarm for %d seconds\n", interval);
    alarm(interval);
    printf("waiting for signal\n");

    int sig_num = sigwait(&sigs, NULL);
    // sigwaitinfo()
    if (sig_num == 0)
    {
        printf("I received the alarm signal, breaking the wait\n");
    }

    else if (sig_num == EINVAL)
    {
        printf("some other error occurred");
        perror("signal wait failed unexpectedly");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int somefunction()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % 4) + 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int alarm_wait = 0;
    setup_alarm();
    while (1)
    {
        // do somework here
        alarm_wait = somefunction();
        // sleep for $alarm_wait or untill we receive SIGALARM
        wait_for_alarm(alarm_wait);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The results I'm getting is that when the execution reaches `sigwait` and I send the `SIGINT` signal(through `ctrl-c`) the program is not interrupted instead it keeps waiting until `$alarm_wait` has elapsed or until I send `SIGALRM`, what I want to do is have the logic only handles `SIGALRM` and every other signal should be handled normally(i.e SIGINT should interrupt the program even while it's waiting for `SIGALRM` signal)

Comment: The second argument to `sigwait()` can't be `NULL`. It has to be a valid pointer.

Comment: Anyways, after fixing that and adding a missing header (`<time.h>`) it compiles and works as expected for me.

Comment: @Shawn I have added a second argument to `sigwait` but it doesn't solve the issue, as for `time.h`, I have `sys/time.h` included which includes `time.h`, my expected result is that when the process is sleeping and waiting for signal for some seconds, if I click `ctrl-c` it should interrupt the wait immediately and quit the program, which is not happening in my case

Comment: Although it might on some systems, `<sys/time.h>` isn't specified to include `<time.h>` or provide a prototype for `time()`, and doesn't on my Linux/glibc system. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html#tag_13_64

Comment: And that's the behavior I got - ctrl-c exits the program at once, otherwise it loops forever.

Comment: @Shawn ok, it seems this is a platform-dependent issue, I tested the code on macOS which showed the issue, testing the code on a Linux machine shows the code work as I expect it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shawn for pointing out the second argument of `sigwait` I was able to solve my issue by also blocking `SIGINT` and using the second argument of `sigwait` to determine if the signal is `SIGINT` then execute `exit(0)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sigset_t sigs;

void setup_alarm()
{
    printf("setting up signals\n");
    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGALRM);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGINT);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, NULL);
}
void wait_for_alarm(int interval)
{
    printf("setting up alarm for %d seconds\n", interval);
    alarm(interval);
    printf("waiting for signal\n");
    int sig;
    int sig_num = sigwait(&sigs, &sig);
    if(sig == SIGINT)
    exit(0);
    if (sig_num == 0)
    {
        printf("I received the alarm signal, breaking the wait\n");
    }

    else if (sig_num == EINVAL)
    {
        printf("some other error occurred");
        perror("signal wait failed unexpectedly");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int somefunction()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % 4) + 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int alarm_wait = 0;
    setup_alarm();
    while (1)
    {
        // do somework here
        alarm_wait = somefunction();
        // sleep for $alarm_wait or untill we receive SIGALARM
        wait_for_alarm(alarm_wait);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code now works as i would expect, i'm not sure if this is the best solution since i'm only handling two signals and don't know how the rest of the signals are being handled(maybe some of these signals are important for the init system for example).
I will leave my answer unaccepted for sometime incase someone has a better solution.